# How can I get all checked check box values?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have my check box control as shown.

```
   <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkdelete" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderNumber") %>' Font-Bold="false" />
   </ItemTemplate>
```

I am trying to delete multiple grid view records using jQuery Ajax call. 
I am trying to get all checked check box values as shown.

```
var checkboxes = [];
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    checkboxes.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: And what's not working? What does that do that you weren't expecting, or not do that you *were* expecting?

Comment: Please provide the rendered/pertinent HTML. You've added ASP.net, but not tagged the question as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want the `Text` attribute of the check box, not the value itself.  This is placed in a `label` element next to the `input[type="checkbox"]`:

```
var checkboxes = [];
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    checkboxes.push($(this).next().text());
});
```

I am not sure if ASP.NET puts the label before or after the input so you may need to use `prev()` instead of `next()`.